# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, unity-container

I tried install unity.mvc4 using NuGet while installing it gave an error because it required .net4.5 framework so I uninstalled it and remove the package file and installed unity.MVC3.

Now I tried to run the application and it gives me the error below.

I checked the web.config and no entry in web.config. I don't know from where it is referring the version=3.0.0. Please help me to resolve the issue. I don't want unity 3.0 version I want unity 2.1.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = xxxxx LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.Unity,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.]
>   Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.DisposeOfChildContainer() +0
>   Unity.Mvc4.RequestLifetimeHttpModule.b__0(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +31
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Answer (score 1):

Within your web.config, add the following in the runtime section:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```